# How to change the stores in the App Store after having added funds?

Tags: ios-appstore

I’m asking this because I need to change from the Romanian store to USA Store so that I can download certain apps. After I have added funds, it doesn’t work anymore. After I have gone to country/origins It shows me this message:

> ”You have a credit balance in the store. You need to use your balance before you can change the stores.”

Can anyone please tell me how to solve this issue in order to change the stores even if I have added funds? I want to download some apps but I can’t. For example, when I wanted to download **Six guns** or **Comedy Central**, I go to internet and it shows me the app, but then I click on it and then it takes me to USA Store, and after I want to download it, it asks me, “do you want to change the App Store to USA STORE?” And I replayed positively, but it didn’t worked as I hoped, it moved me back to Romanian App Store. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not have an USA credit card tying you to an USA address, you won´t be able to buy anything from the USA store.

You might get away changing the store with a new free account, and only with a free account.

As your purpose is buying something from the USA store, I would forget the idea.